# A group theory exercise in Brown's group cohomology book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-cohomology

My question is taken from exercise IV.3.4(b) in Brown's group cohomology book.  Let $E$ be a finitely generated group, and suppose that $C$, the center of $E$, has finite index in $E$, say $[E:C]=n$.  The exercise asks us to show that the commutator subgroup $[E,E]$ is finite.

From part $(a)$ of the same exercise, we have a homomorphism $E\to C$ which is the $n$th power map when restricted to $C$, and the hint given in the book says to notice that this map has a finite kernel.  I'm having trouble seeing this fact.

If it is helpful, the map $E\to C$ is obtained as follows.  Consider the extension

$$1\to C\to E\to E/C=G\to 1$$

This represents an element $\alpha$ in $H^2(G,C)$, and if $f:C\to C$ is the $n$th power map, then $H^2(G,f)(\alpha)=0\in H^2(G,C)$ (this is because $|G|=n$ annihilates cohomology groups).  It follows that there is a map from $E$ to the trivial extension $C\times G$, whose first component is a homomorphism $E\to C$ which restricts to the $n$th power map on $C$ (the extensions must fit into a commutative diagram with $f$).

Hints or answers are much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: How did you get the map $E\to C$? If you have this map, then one way of viewing the commutator subgroup is as the smallest normal subgroup $H$ with the property that $G/H$ is abelian. Therefore since $E/\ker(E\to C)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $C$ (and so is abelian), we must have that $[E,E]\subseteq\ker(E\to C)$. Now you only have to prove that the kernel of this homomorphism is finite, which shouldn't be hard to do.

Comment: @RobertAuffarth: Thanks for the insight.  I've described how $E\to C$ is constructed in the question.